# HTML:JS:BOOTSTRAP ; validate the multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap

In my web application we have used the twitter-bootstrap theme. I have to do client side validation for one form in my application. The form includes text fields,checkboxs and multiselect dropdowns. I can validate textfield and checkboxes but i cant validate the dropdown.

```
 <select id="users" name="username[]"  class="chzn-select span2" multiple="multiple">  
     <option value="sdfsd">sdfsdfs</option>
           .... 
   </select>
```

But during runtime the select tag is hide and they generate `<li>` tags.
I cant use document.getElementByID();

Please provide me the best way to do the validation.

Comment: Please do not use [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has noting to do with this plugin.  Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<form action="#">
<select id="users" name="username[]"  class="chzn-select span2" multiple="multiple"> 
      <option value=""></option>  
     <option value="sdfsd">sdfsdfs</option>
           .... 
</select>
<input type="submit" id="add_btn">
</form>
```

Script

```
$('#add_btn').on('click', function(e) {
        if($('#users').val() == null && $('#users_chosen').is(':visible')) {
        alert('You must choose division');
        }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VSpa3/284/)

OR

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
         var options = $('#users > option:selected');
         if(options.length == 0){
             alert('no value selected');
             return false;
         }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aDxu8/1/)

Comment: I guess he asked something like this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: but @user3069614 mentioned twitter-bootstrap theme in question and posted code that contains **Chosen**

Comment: ya i know it will works with all platforms what problem you have in this?

Answer (score 1):

```
//You can use Js for this
    var ptype=document.getElementById('username').options[document.getElementById('username').selectIndex].value;

if(ptype=""){
document.getElementById('username').style.display='none';
alert('Please select field');
document.getElementById('username').focus();
return false;
}
```